# paypal integration with firebase functions has errors in logs

Tags: firebase, payment-gateway, google-cloud-functions

I am trying for 3 days to solve this problem but I couldn't.
what I am doing is **integrating paypal payment with my android application using firebase cloud functions.**

I integrated paypal successfully on my android app. but when i shifted to the second step which is making http triggered function to complete integration I used this code on index.js on cloud functions.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const paypal=require('paypal-rest-sdk');
const admin=require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

paypal.configure({
    mode:"sandbox",
    client_id:functions.config().paypal.client_id,
    client_secret:functions.config().paypal.client_secret
});
//Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.payout = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const sender_batch_id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(9);
    const sync_mode ='true';
    const payReq = JSON.stringify({
        sender_batch_header: {
            sender_batch_id: sender_batch_id,
            email_subject: "You have a payment"
        },
        items: [
            {
                recipient_type: "EMAIL",
                amount: {
                    value: 0.1,
                    currency: "USD"
                },
                receiver: "ammah6600@crowns.com",
                note: "Thank you.",
                sender_item_id: "item_3"
            }
        ]
    });
    paypal.payout.create(payReq,sync_mode,(error,payout) =>{
        if(error){
            console.warn(error.response);
            response.status('500').end();
            throw error;
        }else{
            console.info("payout created");
            console.info(payout);
            response.status('200').end();
        }
    });
});
```

****but**
I found these problems in Logs of firebase functions**
1-

```
 `
{ name: 'SYNC_MODE_NOT_APPLICABLE',
  message: 'Synchronous mode will soon be deprecated and is no longer available for new integrations. You can use the asynchronous mode by specifying sync_mode= false in the request.',
  debug_id: '393880ab5b7a9',
  information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors',
  httpStatusCode: 403 }`
```

2

```
-Error: Response Status : 403
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/client.js:130:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Then I changed sunc_mode to false but i found these problems appeared to me:
1-

```
{ name: 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS',
  debug_id: 'b2a6e96353ee7',
  message: 'Sender does not have sufficient funds. Please add funds and retry.',
  information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors',
  httpStatusCode: 422 }
```

2-

```
Error: Response Status : 422
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/client.js:130:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Please help me in reviewing my codes or credentials
regarding that my country is egypt
my merchant account is us also receiver account